# CMS Storage Systems

Tags: asp.net, design-patterns, content-management-system

How do you prefer to manage the contents of your site ,

**XSLT , SQL , Sharepoint** or ... or maybe a **mixed** version ,

For example you have **articles** , **products** , **blogs**

I saw in different codes that every developer used a *different mechanism to store their data* ,
What is yours ? what do you prefer in different cases ? what is the reason ?

Maybe I use **Databases** for all kind of data , if so what will be the weaknesses of doing so ?

With using databases as a whole solution for everything in the site , we can search our data , analyze the data from any point that we want , getting the statistics  and any kind of processing through our data will be possible .

I'm not very familiar with **sharepoint** because I was busy with other technologies , just I had a glance look at it

thanks for your participation

**Edited : --------------**
I hope more people to come and give their point of views , thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have designed a bespoke CMS system that holds data in a database then 'publishes' it to xml. The XML is then used with xslt templates to display the pages which are then cached for speed.

I'd be interesting to know if anyone else is doing something similar.

Josh

Comment: What is the benefit of the intermediate XML format between database and display?

Comment: less load on the database - can transform the xslt directly from the file system - can reuse xml files without extra database calls - for example i output a 'navigation' xml file which is used on all the pages.

Comment: So actually you are caching results, but you could do that without XML and just wrap data into an object.

Answer (score 1):

I think a database offers the best overall solution for storing data in a CMS. It does have some drawbacks, but so do all the other storage alternatives on the market.

I've blogged a bit about content modeling and how the different storage technologies impact how you can define your content model: 
http://www.webnodes.com/get-more-out-of-your-content-content-modeling-and-data-stores